# integration by u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

U- substitution problem is as follows;
$$\int (x^{3}+1)^{2}3x^{2}dx$$\
answer pretty easy;
$$\dfrac{(x^{3}+1)^{3}}{3}+C$$\now question, when went to check and compare doing with and without the u-substitution got the following;

Without u-substitution(just multiply the integrand out;
$$\int (3x^{8}+6x^{5}+3x^{2})dx=\dfrac{1}{3}x^{9}+x^{6}+x^{3}+C$$\

now , to check, multiply out the result of the u-substituion;

$$ \dfrac{(x^{3}+1)^{3}}{3}+C=\dfrac{1}{3}x^{9}+x^{6}+x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{3}+C$$\

so hopefully you see my question, $$\dfrac{(x^{3}+1)^{3}}{3}$$\
 when multiplied out, generates an additional 1/3?  Does this just get folded into the constant?
What to make of it?

Comment: Yes, it just gets folded into the constant of integration. Two functions that differ by a constant have the same derivative and are both antiderivatives of that it.

Comment: And it should have been $\frac{1}{3}$, not 1.

Comment: Thanks.....for the replies...BScott and simple, and yes 1/3 not 1!!!

Now, naturally, when differentiating, the extra 1/3 goes away, and we arrive back at the integrand...but, am still bothered,...must there not be some interpretation for the extra 1/3?

Answer (score 1):

If we consider indefinite integrals, the answer is that an additional constant is absorbed into the integration constant, because it's not an extra degree of freedom in the set of antiderivatives. If we consider definite integrals, we note that $\int_0^x(t^3+1)^23t^2dt$ can be evaluated as$$[\tfrac13(t^3+1)^3]_a^x=\tfrac13((x^3+1)^3-(a^3+1)^3)$$by substitution or$$[\tfrac13t^9+t^6+t^3+C]_1^a=\tfrac13(x^9-a^9)+x^6-a^6+x^3-a^3$$by expanding the factorized integrand. You can verify these agree for any $a$.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the same integration integration $I=\int f(x) dx$ by two different methogs.
You get $I_1(x)$ and $I_2(x)$, they may differ by constant only.$$I_1(x)-I_2(x)=\text{constant ~independent of $x$}.$$, Check that your case $$I_1(x)-I_2(x)=1$$